# How to import stylesheets and include attributes

Tags: css

In CSS, is there a way to import a stylesheet and include the attributes such as `rel='stylesheet'`, `id='responsive-css'`, `media='all'` in the `@import` statement?

For example:

```
@import url("style.css?ver=4.2.2" ) rel='stylesheet', id='responsive-css', media='all';
```

Comment: An id is associated with an HTML element. In the case of `@import` there is not HTML element, hence no ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import) you can specify the media in the @import as such

```
@import url("fineprint.css") print;
```

for the `rel="stylesheet",` @import is already css , you should'nt need it. and since it's not a tag you can't really put an id on it.